# Asus AiMesh drops connection momentarily

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a mesh network with an ASUS RT-AC68U as the primary router and an ASUS RT-AC1900P as the AiMesh node.  The RT-AC68U connects to the ISP cable modem using ethernet cable.  Since original post I added a second RT-AC68U to the mesh network to give coverage in the rear yard/patio area. Issue seems same

The systems are running the latest firmware, Version: 3.0.0.4.386_49703-gc2cdfc8, and the issue has happening over several firmware updates.

The systems connected to the node RT-AC1900P are unable to access the internet and the primary RT-AC68U cannot be pinged. The Asus Android app shows the RT-AC68U but the RT-AC1900P node is missing.

After a few moments, sometimes less than a minute, the node reappears and the network functions as normal.

There are about 20 clients total but no large bandwidth uses.  No streaming of any kind.  The primary node is on the main floor and the second node is on the second floor. The building is wood frame construction and distance is about 30 feet between the two.  When the link is up download speed is around 175Mbps and upload 10-20Mbps.  Sometimes it will see 190Mbps down.

Windows device event logs show no errors at time of the loss of connection. There are sometimes event ID 1014 "Name resolution for the name "*DNS name of an active connection to a web page*" timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded."   The event does not seem to match the loss of connection other than the web page tried to do something with DNS during the outage.

The Asus routers are configured to use ISP DNS servers.  "WAN DNS Setting: Connect to DNS Server automatically" I have not changed to any DNS such as Google, Cloudflare or OpenDNS as the issue seems to be between the two nodes.

Online searches find others with this issue but there does not seem to be a resolution.  Some suggest a cable link between the two nodes but that is not easily accomplished in this building.  Nothing at ASUS.  Just chatted and so real help.  Send in and after paying CAN$50 per unit we will let you know if we can fix and how much.